# FinTecSystem implement GET request XS2A

Tags: javascript, security

is here anybody who have experience with FinTecSystem? I want to implement get request to its API and wondering if anybody of you had already done this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it answers your question, but we have implemented XS2A based Demo system:
https://github.com/adorsys/open-banking-gateway

It includes:

1. FinTech example application
2. TPP application (OpenBankingGateway)
3. XS2A ASPSP (bank) Sandbox

You can check our OpenApi documentation of these applications, to see what is necessary for `GET /accounts` request:

1. FinTech - https://obg-dev-fintechserver.cloud.adorsys.de/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/fintech_api.yml
2. TPP - https://obg-dev-openbankinggateway.cloud.adorsys.de/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/tpp_banking_api_ais.yml

You can either build it from sources or play with our DEV environment:
https://obg-dev-fintechui.cloud.adorsys.de

If you go to https://obg-dev-fintechui.cloud.adorsys.de, you will see FinTech demo interface, where you can login with some random login/password pair

Or you can follow instructions at:
https://github.com/adorsys/open-banking-gateway/blob/develop/docs/demo_env.md